# Stop SQL Server 2008 retrieving a 'space' character when selecting blank field

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, field

I am having a problem with SQL Server that has appeared recently. When a select statement calls an empty field(doesnt have a NULL value but there is no data inside) it produces a 'space' character. I have been testing with 2x 2008 R2 SQL Servers and one works and one doesn't. There have been no updates from Windows and the PHP versions are the same. This has just randomly started.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Show your table structure and your code. We aren't great mind-readers...

Comment: just trim() the field when you read it.

Comment: @GordonM no `TRIM()` in SQL Server, only `LTRIM()/RTRIM()`, and it might not be a space, it could be a tab, carriage return, or some other whitespace character - those aren't affected by trimming but could still be rendered as a space (or appear to be).

Comment: I meant PHP trim(), as the question is tagged PHP.  If PHP isn't relevant to the particular problem you're having then the question shouldn't be tagged PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look at what is stored in the data field.  That is the first place to start!

Is it defined not null in the table definition.

The example below sets up a temp table will the last three entries looking like blank.

```
--
-- Setup sample table
--

-- Sample table
create table #blanks
( 
    blanks_id int identity (1, 1),
    blanks_txt varchar(64)
);
go

-- Add null, space, empty string, hex codes
insert into #blanks (blanks_txt) values (null);
insert into #blanks (blanks_txt) values (space(10));
insert into #blanks (blanks_txt) values ('');
insert into #blanks (blanks_txt) values (char(9));
go

-- Last three entries show as blank
select * from #blanks
```

Use the following snippet to find out what is in the field.

```
-- Code to find out internal data values
select 
    blanks_id,
    datalength(blanks_txt) as size, 
    cast(blanks_txt as varbinary(64)) as buffer 
from #blanks
```

Output from both code executions.

[image]